# How to make sure that I do not compare two lists with the same size and content in reverse direction

Tags: python, loops

I would like to make two for loops over two list with the size of 4.

```
list_01 = [0,1,2,3] and list_02 = [0,1,2,3]
```

I have already done a statement like this:

```
for ii in range(len(list_01)):
  for jj in range(len(list_02)):

  # if list_01[ii] != list_02[jj]:
    if list_01[0] != list_02[1]:
       ...
```

I would like to avoid doing the "same" in the reverse direction like this:

```
  # if list_01[ii] != list_02[jj]:
    if list_01[1] != list_02[0]:
       ...
```

Just compare each of the values with each other one time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add example with desired output?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you me to by "prevent to do the same" in the reverse direction? Do you mean you want to exclude the example where `list_02 = [3, 2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: `if list_01[jj] != list_02[ii]`?

Comment: if i allready compared like `ii = 0 to jj = 1`, i would like to stop compare `ii = 1 and jj = 0`. just for example.

Comment: You might have to change the beginning of the inner loop to `ii` for that case, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare `list_01[ii] != list_02[jj]` such that `ii <= jj`, then just make sure you start from `ii` instead of from `0` in the inner loop:

```
for ii in range(len(list_01)):
  # start at ii, not 0, to maintain invariant that ii <= jj
  for jj in range(ii, len(list_02)):
    if list_01[ii] != list_02[jj]:
      # do stuff
```

**EDIT:** As comments have observed, this is not very Pythonic. Might be better to avoid the indices and just get the items you need more directly:

```
for ii, item_01 in enumerate(list_01):
  for item_02 in list_02[ii:]: # slice from ii to end
    if item_01 != item_02:
      # do stuff
```

Comment: You might also want to mention the `enumerate` function, which is considered better practice than `range(len())`.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Updated to reflect your comments. Was just trying to keep OPs original intentions...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to omit same pairs of indices, this should do it:

```
from itertools import product

list_01 = [0,1,2,3]
list_02 = [0,1,2,3]

i1 = range(len(list_01))
i2 = range(len(list_02))

indices = []

for p in product(i1, i2):
    if sorted(p) not in indices:
        indices.append(list(p))

for i, j in indices:
    #do stuff
```